# SVD proof to If $A$ is of full rank, then $A^{*}A$ is of full rank

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank, svd

> Provided $A$ is a full rank matrix $\in\mathbb{C^{m\times n}}$, then $A^{*}A$ is of full rank. Suppose $m\gt n$.

There is a solution to this problem: [solution link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632525/if-a-is-full-column-rank-then-ata-is-always-invertible), and the top solution makes sense to me.

But when I use SVD to solve this problem:

since $A=U\Sigma V^{*}$
then $A^{*}A =V\Sigma^{*}U^{*}U\Sigma V^{*}= V\Sigma^{*}\Sigma V^{*}$
$rank(A^{*}A)=rank(\Sigma^{*}\Sigma)$
because $rank(\Sigma)=n$, $rank(A^{*}A)=n$

I got a quite different answer. Where is error in my SVD proof?

Comment: why do you think there's an error?

Comment: $A^*A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, so what's the problem?

Comment: since $rank(A^{*}A=n$, it is not necessarily a full rank matrix, because ${A^{*}A}$ is a matrix of $m\times m$. Then it is not invertible.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with dimension here.

Answer (score 0):

Given a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}_{n}$, the singular value decomposition is
$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} &=
  \mathbf{U} \, \Sigma \, \mathbf{V}^{*} \\
%
 &=
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \mathbf{S}_{\rho\times \rho} \\
     \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
  \end{array} \right]  \\
%
%
\end{align}
$$
The unitary matrix $\color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.

The matrix product 
$$
\mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} = 
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}} \\ 
  \end{array} \right]
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S} & \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}^{*}_{\mathcal{R}}} \\
     \color{red}{\mathbf{U}^{*}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
%
% U 
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{R}}} & \color{red}{\mathbf{U}_{\mathcal{N}}}
  \end{array} \right]  
% Sigma
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
     \mathbf{S} \\
     \mathbf{0} 
  \end{array} \right]
% V 
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*} \\ 
  \end{array} \right] 
%
=
% V 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}
  \, \mathbf{S}^{2} \,
% V 
  \color{blue}{\mathbf{V}_{\mathcal{R}}}^{*}
%
$$