# Relation of $det(AA^T)$ and $det(A^TA)$ with Range and Nullspaces of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

While I was studying for my exam, I found this question about range and nullspaces of a matrix, which seemed easy at the first glance, but I couldn't find a way to prove it. Could you please take a look at it?

Let $A\in R^{mxn}$

Prove that:

i) If $R(A) = R^m \implies det(AA^T)\neq0.$

ii)If $N(A)=\{0\} \implies det(A^TA)\neq0$

Comment: And of [If $A$ is full column rank, then $A^TA$ is always invertible](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/632525). Please search before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (ii), note that
$$
\det(A'A)=0\implies\exists x\neq 0:A'Ax=0\implies 0=x'A'Ax=|Ax|^2\implies 0\neq x\in N(A).
$$
For (i), we use (ii) along with the observation that $R(A)=\mathbb{R}^m$ implies $N(A')=\{0\}$. Indeed, suppose there is some $x\neq 0$, $x\in\mathbb{R^m}$ such that $A'x=0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Claim that $A$ cannot map to $x$ (which means the surjectivity of $A$ will be violated). Suppose otherwise:
$$
\exists\beta\in\mathbb{R}^n: A\beta=x\implies 0=A'x=A'A\beta\implies 0=\beta'A'A\beta=|A\beta|^2=|x|^2
$$
which would imply $x=0$. But this would be a contradiction because we have supposed $x\neq 0$.