# Rank Question- with adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was hoping for help with a math practice problem for an exam from my book.

We are wanted to use the property $\operatorname{Ker}(A)=\operatorname{Ker}(A^*A)$ to show:

a) Rank(A)=rank(A*A)

b) IF Ax=0 has only the trivial solution, A is left invertible.

I am very unsure as to how to start this problem so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction!

Comment: What do you denote $A^*$?

Comment: For $(a)$ you just need the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).  Is $(b)$ supposed to be an if ... then statement or are you saying $\operatorname{Ker}(A)=\operatorname{Ker}(A^*A)$ implies both of those properties?

Comment: A* is denoting the adjoint

Comment: To use the rank nullity theorem can you say the dim(Ker(A))=dim(Ker(A* A)) and since they are both in V we use this to say dim(Im(A))=dim(Im(A* A)) since dim(ker)+dim(im)=dim(V) so then we know they have the same dimension of the image, which is the same as rank?

Comment: Given your edit, you can use the rank-nullity theorem for $(b)$ as well.

Comment: One little change, $A$ and $A^*A$ both *have domain $V$* -- they're not both *in $V$*.  Other than that, yes.  That's the argument.

Comment: how would you use rank-nullity for b)?

Comment: $Ax=0$ has only trivial solution $\implies$ nullity = 0 $\implies$ rank = $\dim(V)$ $\implies$ what?

Comment: so that would make it invertible, ah I see that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Well, [there are a couple of extra steps](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632525/if-a-is-full-column-rank-then-ata-is-always-invertible).  But yeah, it eventually implies that $A$ is left invertible (hint: if you can't immediately see where to go from the link, try multiplying the equation $Ax=0$ by $A^*$).